# how to pass a value using android navigation if the default value null

Tags: android, navigation, android-safe-args

I'm using android navigation components with safe args.
I set that the argument is null-able and default value as null too.

The problem is when I want to pass any value an error is shown:

```
required: no arguments
found: Character
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

My fragment XML code:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/bookListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bookstory.UI.Fragments.BookListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_book_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_list">
            <argument
            android:name="character"
            app:argType="com.example.bookstory.DAO.Character"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
</fragment>
```

My action:

```
      <action
            android:id="@+id/action_bookDescriptionFragment_to_bookListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bookListFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/bookListFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

I can't understand what is the problem - when I delete the default value it is OK.

Comment: How do you pass the value?.. you didn't include that

Comment: @Zain 
```
ClassNameDirections.ActionName action = ClassNameDirections.actionName( character);
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `ClassNameDirections.ActionName action = ClassNameDirections.actionName(character);`
> `Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);`

As your action id is `action_bookDescriptionFragment_to_bookListFragment`

```
  <action
        android:id="@+id/action_bookDescriptionFragment_to_bookListFragment"
```

Then it can be utilized in [this navigate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(androidx.navigation.NavDirections)) method version that takes in a `NavDirections` arg:

```
findNavController().navigate(BookListFragmentDirections.actionBookDescrioptionFragmentToBookListFragment()
```

This won't pass in a value, but to do so:

As your value is named as `character`:

```
 <argument
        android:name="character"
        app:argType="com.example.bookstory.DAO.Character"
        app:nullable="true"
        android:defaultValue="@null" />
```

Then you can cascade the action with the safeArgs generated `setCharacter()` method:

```
findNavController().navigate(BookListFragmentDirections.actionBookDescrioptionFragmentToBookListFragment()
                    .setCharacter("c")
```

I see that you use safeArgs, but just in case you don't want to use it; you can use [this navigate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(kotlin.Int,android.os.Bundle)) method version to set the value through a bundle object

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about safeArgs but if you don't get an answer using safeArgs, that's how you do it with normal bundle.

if you don't know you can send a bundle containing your data along the navigation action as a second parameter to the method.
like that

```
char char_value = 'a' ;
Bundle data = new Bundle() ;
data.putChar("key",char_value);
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_bookDescriptionFragment_to_bookListFragment,data);
```

and in booklistFragment you just call getArguments() anywhere inside the fragment to get this bundle like this

```
public class BookListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle data = getArguments() ;
    char receivedChar = data.getChar("key",'z'); // 'z' is a default value incase it didn't find the key you're looking for it returns 'z'
    }
```

where you can put in a bundle a variety of things, just type 'put' and see what the AutoComplete suggests.

incase of using the bundle, you don't need to add the `argument` part in the nav_graph xml.